# When maximizing a form controls don't move properly

Tags: c#, winforms

When I want to maximize my form I have always to unenable maximize button, because when I want to maximize it, the controls don't feet the new screen size so that they are always at top-left side after maximizing. My QUESTION is: how to maximize the form so it fit the new size??

No actual answer. I have understand the tableLayoutPanel now. It is very beautiful

Comment: Is this WinForms? WPF? Something else?

Comment: Dr. Seuss would be proud of this question.

Comment: FYI the opposite of "enable" is "disable".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Play with the `.Anchor` property of the controls so they move where they are supposed to move when you maximize.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found so far is using `TableLayoutPanel`. You can use nested TableLayoutPanels inside each other to organize your UI. For each UI component, you have to set property `Dock` to `Fill` (including TableLayoutPanels).

That way, you will have robust UI configuring itself automatically when size changes.